# How is the fault tolerance measured?

Tags: blockchain, consensus

“If the number of nodes that agree exceeds **2/3**, the blocks or transactions of clients will be accepted”

Practical Byzantine fault tolerance (pBFT) : **(n - 1) / 3**

I read those 2 things in a PDF that a friend of mine sent me.

The question is: are those numbers (2/3) or “(n-1)/3” constant? Or those numbers are established by the developers.

What makes those numbers? What’s the reason for 2/3 and not 2.5/3 ?  Or why not **(n - 2 ) / 3**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Byzantine fault-tolerant consensus - Why 33% threshold](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/58907/byzantine-fault-tolerant-consensus-why-33-threshold)

Comment: It talks about why those numbers but not how they are measured

Comment: Where are you getting those nonsense numbers from? Those don't reflect anything about how the network operates at all.

Comment: They are not nonsense. They are written on the Practical Byzantine fault PDF. It does reflect how the network operates (Not for Bitcoin’s blockchain though)